# Exiting application with if function

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a problem with exiting the application with the if function, even though i have set the condition and using Application.Exit but error tells me that it can only appear on left hand side of += or -=. How do I go about it?

```
    int a=0;
    int b=a++;

    if(b==10)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: Why not include the full error message?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? How is this code failing to accomplish that?

Comment: There's not enough to go on in your question. What line of code does the exception report as the cause?

Comment: I think you are trying to use an event as a function, which is why you get the error message that you described. If I am not too mistaken, you are looking for this Application.Current.Terminate();

Comment: Yes Louis, that is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Apologies to everyone for not making the question clear.

Answer (score 2):

As you know this case is diffrent in c#, there are two types of using 
operator (++).

> a++ and ++a.

In first case firstly doing operation =, then ++.
But after operation =, result mustn't change, so operation a++ isn't
working.
In second case firstly ++, then =.

> b = ++a;

will return 1.

```
    class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double x;
        x = 1.5;
        Console.WriteLine(++x);
        x = 1.5;
        Console.WriteLine(x++);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

> ```
> Output
> 2.5
> 1.5
> 2.5
> ```

If you make your code :

```
int a=0;
int b=++a;

if(b==10)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

or

```
int a=0;
int b+=a;

if(b==10)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

It will work and if you want to close your mobile application you should use

```
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

for it.You can look [Application.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Terminate](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_terminate_a_Windows_Phone_app)